# query and insert simultaneously to a mongodb collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

What will happen to query and insert simultaneously to a mongodb collection.

For example,

process-I:

```
for page in coll.find():
     # access page
```

process-II:

```
for page in gen_pages():
     # coll.insert(page)
```

Will the `find()` in process-I return the new insertions from process-II?

Suppose that coll is huge and process-II will terminate before process-I

Sincere Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursors are [not isolated](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/) in MongoDB. So, assuming that the `find` method uses a MongoDB cursor internally (which I believe it does), the results are affected by changes to the data from inserts, etc. So, depending on the nature of the query and the data that was inserted, the new values could appear in the results. There are a number of factors including where the cursor is currently pointing, sorting, when locks are taken, number of documents requested by the cursor operation, ....

Comment: So it's random? and only be analysed case by case?

Comment: Oh, actually I found it following your link. Thanks. Not isolated means everything can be random. Thanks~

Comment: Of course, it's not random, but it may seem unpredictable given the factors that come into play. There are a LOT of factors.